# SQL2005 Express Machine believes it's part of a Cluster fails to Upgrade

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, installation

I have a machine where I am attempting to upgrade from Sql2005 Express to Sql2008r2 Express, but it is failing on the Rules check.

> Rule Check Result
>
> Rule "Not clustered or the cluster
>   service is up and online." failed.
>
> The machine is clustered, but the
>   cluster is not online or cannot be
>   accessed from one of its nodes. To
>   continue determine why the cluster is
>   not online and rerun setup instead of
>   rerunning the rule since the rule can
>   no longer detect a cluster environment
>   correctly.

I know the machine is not part of a Cluster, and it's actually running on Windows Xp(POSReady 2009). Is there some registry keys or files that are somehow fooling the Sql2008r2 Express installer to believe that it's in a Cluster. That I can delete or change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going heavy in deleting all the registry keys, installer registry keys, old database files, directories, service control manager entries etc. and reinstalling.

SQl2005 express on this machine was in a weird state, when you attempted to uninstall it just exited from the uninstall process.

These machines are imaged by a Hardware supplier and only get into this state if you install SQl2005 on them and then attempt to upgrade to 2008r2.

If you install 2008r2 first there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have known good backups, it is likely to be safer (what other issues are lurking?) to uninstall 2005 and then install 2008R2.

Comment: it won't uninstall either

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by running the following commands from an administrative command prompt. Locate this 
directory: %systemroot%\system32\wbem
Run these commands in sequence & restart your setup.

Comment: um...have you forgotten the rest of your answer?